# Checking for a palindrome

Tags: c++, c++11, palindrome

What I'm basically wondering is if there's anything that is possible to improve in this C++ code:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>

bool is_palindromic(std::string s)
{
    std::size_t i = 0;
    std::size_t j = s.length() - 1;
    while (i < j) {
        if (s[i++] != s[j--]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yep. Try a for loop. Learn how to use references. Consider accidental mutation.

Comment: Stepping outside the C++ code a bit, make sure you have a clear definition of what qualifies as a palindrome. Are there things (such as spaces or punctuation or letter case) that should be ignored: "Sir, I’m Iris." or just "SIRIMIRIS"?

Comment: "A man a plan a canal Panama" also considered a palindrome.

Comment: "A man a plan a canal Panama" that's not a palindrome...

Comment: @Max Yes it is. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155556/amanap-lanac-a-nalp-a-nam-a

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to offer a different angle of better. This code could be more generic. Why is it tied to exactly `std::string` - what if I need to check palindromic nature of `std::wstring` or the contents of a `std::vector<T>`? How about `std::list<T>` or `std::map<T>` (if palindromic can even mean anything on a `std::map`)? Here's how you can handle all of those with a single function:

```
template <typename Sequence>
bool is_palindromic(const Sequence& seq)
{
    auto count = seq.size() / 2; // rounded down is fine, as a middle element matches itself
    auto i = seq.begin();        // prefer std::begin(seq) in C++14
    auto j = seq.rbegin();       // prefer std::rbegin(seq) in C++14

    for (Sequence::size_type c = 0; c < count; ++c, ++i, ++j)
    {
        if (*i != *j)
            return false;
    }
    return true; // considers sequences without mismatched characters to be palindromes
}
```

Note that I incorporated the other comments I agree with - in particular passing by const reference, and using the sequence's `size_type`. I'm not sure how to best support arrays, however; while `std::[r]begin` will handle arrays, I don't believe arrays have a `.size()` or `::size_type` to use. I guess that means they need their own overload, or at least some overloaded helpers.

Comment: Use `std::distance(std::begin(seq), std::end(seq))` if you want to have a generic way to handle the size. With it, you can handle arrays. I don't know whether it is specialized for random-access iterators; if not, your code may be slower.

Comment: Ah, `std::distance` sounds great for random access and thus supporting arrays. However it's linear on non-random access, so would be slower on `std::list` (though no worse algorithmically). Thanks for the idea at least!

Answer (score 8):

First of all, you should pass the `std::string` by const reference and not by value, therefore, replace `std::string s` by `const std::string& s`, otherwise you will make a whole copy of the string everytime you invoke the function.

Also, you program may crash if the `std::string` is empty since you're doing `std::size_t j = s.length() - 1;`. If `s.length() == 0`, `j` will probably be a big number and you will end up with a segfault due to an out of range index.

As suggested by Loki in the comments, you could also use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop in order for your code to look cleaner.

Yet another suggestion by Jamal: using `std::string::size_type` instead of `std::size_t` (and removing `#include <cstddef>` by the way) would be more idiomatic. The type returned by `std::string::length` is not required to be `std::size_t` but `std::string::size_type`.

Therefore, I would rewrite it as:

```
bool is_palindromic(const std::string& s)
{
    if (s.empty())
    {
        // You can return true if you think that
        // an empty string is a palyndrome
        return false;
    }
    for (std::string::size_type i=0, j=s.length()-1
         ; i < j ; ++i, --j)
    {
        if (s[i] != s[j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: +1 looks good.  Just one nitpick: use `std::string::size_type` instead of `std::size_t`.

Comment: Looks like you want `--j` instead of `++j`.

Comment: +1 for it's proximity to the original version and for catching the **empty case** !

Comment: ...BTW: isn't an empty string a palindrome?

Comment: I'd agree, if there was something special referred in the question, maybe a definition like [this](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Projects/P0/proj0.faq.html#ques18). In lack of such, I prefer the idea of empty strings as palindromes.

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to chime in with the "lazy" (if not performant) way of doing this, using reverse iterators:

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s)
{
    return s == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend());
}
```

This is very simple and very readable. You could expand this to do things like remove punctuation if you want, but it gets a bit trickier (although it's still short):

```
// Note that the pass by value is intentional here, so we don't modify
// the original string when using std::remove_if
bool is_palindrome(std::string s)
{
    auto it = std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return !std::isalpha(c); });
    return std::equal(s.begin(), it, std::reverse_iterator<std::string::iterator>(it));
}
```

This can likewise be made into a template that will work with any sequence with very little effort.

Answer (score 5):

Searching for something as **symmetrical** as palindromes themselves, I came to this somewhat picturesque solution, that doesn't handle the empty string in a specific way, but as palindromic:

```
#include <string>

bool is_palindromic(const std::string& s)
{
    std::string::const_iterator start = s.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = s.end();
    while (start < end) {
        if (*(start++) != *(--end)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Its **major drawback** is the redundant check for self-equality of the central char.